# Allow vote changes after comments

Tags: discussion, voting

We're allowed to change our votes after questions or answers are edited.

I assume this is because a question or answer which previously had inadequate details or was inadequately clear could be fixed through edits. Something that was downvote worthy before might become no-vote worthy, for example.

Sometimes the clarification doesn't come in the main content via an edit, though. Sometimes the clarification comes via a comment.

It seems to me that we should allow votes to change after comments are added.

Example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37008989/901641

I originally downvoted that answer. After a comment 10 minutes later, I noticed I had missed some details. My vote is already locked in though, so I can't undo that downvote.

Comment: No, such improvements and clarifications should be incorporated in the question itself. You should ask the OP to do so.

Comment: ^^^^^---- since comments are prone to get deleted over time...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's assuming there was a problem with the post that someone commented with a fix for.  If someone commented with an explanation for why the post is wrong, and another comment explains why the criticism of the post is wrong, there may well be nothing to add to the answer; it was right all along.

Comment: @JustDoIt Why would the comment later getting deleted be an issue here?

Comment: Cause any clarification would be lost if its in the comments, that's why the post should edited with the appropriate clarifications @Servy

Comment: @JustDoIt You're assuming that there would need to be clarifications to edit into the post, and that isn't always going to be the case.

Comment: By clarifications I mean fixes too, and if its not the case then that's great, but what if its the case?Should we leave the clarification in the comment? @Servy

Comment: @JustDoIt I'm not saying you shouldn't edit answers when a comment points out a problem with it, I'm saying not all comments are going to be pointing out a problem that should result in the post being edited, even though that comment might influence someone's opinion of the quality of the answer.  My claim that *some* comments won't result in an edit to the post isn't a claim that *no* comments should result in an edit to the post.

Comment: And I was referring only to comments that points out a problem with the post that result in an edit. We just got lost in the middle @Servy I get were you're coming from

Comment: As an example, [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322329/allow-vote-changes-after-comments?noredirect=1#comment340286_322329) is a comment that responds to a criticism of another post, explaining why that criticism isn't valid for the post.  If the person that posted the original criticism downvoted the post, but has since changed their opinion, they cannot change their vote, and yet since the original post is fine all along, there is nothing to edit in the post to enable edits.

Comment: @Servy perfectly illustrates this. All 3 of the downvoters now wish they could upvote, but the very issue being protested prevents them from doing so. Irony.

Comment: I really think vote changes should be allowed much more generally, whether there is a comment or not.  After all, we may have had time to reflect ("I was too harsh") or even had a bad mouse that chose the wrong option...